# How to save UIImages at app directory with NSUserDefaults and show them in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage, nsuserdefaults

I am saving UIImages data paths to an array in NSUserDefaults, but only the first time the app is launched

```
func saveImages() ->Bool{
    if let isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce = defaults.stringForKey("isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce"){
        //App already launched
        return true
    }
    else{
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce")
       //App launched first time

    var images = [UIImage(named: "apple"), UIImage(named: "banana")]
    var dataVoid = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(images[0]),UIImagePNGRepresentation(images[1])]
    var imagesDatas = [dataVoid[0],dataVoid[1]]

    var documentsDirectory:String?
    var paths:[AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

    if paths.count > 0 {

        documentsDirectory = paths[0] as? String
        var savePaths = [documentsDirectory! + "/apple", documentsDirectory! + "banana"]
        for index in savePaths{
            for secondIndex in imagesDatas {

        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(index, contents: secondIndex, attributes: nil)

            }
        }

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(savePaths, forKey: "NSSavePaths")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

      }
    }
        return false
}
```

Then I call the array from NSUserdefaults and store it in a variable in viewDidLoad

```
 var arraySavePaths:NSArray = []

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
           saveImages()
           arraySavePaths = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("NSSavePaths")  as! NSArray
           table.reloadData()  
     }
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath I assign the uiimages to each cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: arraySavePaths[indexPath.row] as! String)

    return cell
}
```

This works the first time the app is launched

[image]

The problem is that the second time the app is launched (when `saveImages()` isn't called) it doesn't display anything, what can I be doing wrong?

[image: Second launch]

Comment: Have you tried moving the contents of viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear?

Answer (score 0):

i guess the 'image path' cause this problem.

File URL and File path is different.

save the File URL and use UIImage(initWithContentURL) or
save the File path and use UIImage(initWithContentPath)

and also check the file is saved success?